# Which Ubuntu version is best for my old heap Intel Celeron 540 @ 1.86 Ghz with 2 GB RAM

Tags: system-installation

Hey guys I am complete newbee to Linux and would like some sound advice as to which version of Ubuntu I should install on my computer currently running an extremely extremely slow XP ( I am so sick of it ) it is all very confusing for me from what i read on the internet. Please help me with one single solution. I would be really really grateful. Thanks in advance and best wishes.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you try the version **16.04.1 LTS**, architecture 32-bit alias i386 and the flavours

- Lubuntu with the ultra light desktop environment LXDE (first choice)
- Xubuntu with the medium light desktop environment XFCE
- Ubuntu MATE with the medium light desktop environment MATE

Try them live (booted from a USB pendrive or a DVD disk) before deciding what works best for you. See this link,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)